# Getting a safe access to a computational server

Tags: linux, ssh, security, vmware-vsphere, port-forwarding

*Disclaimer: I'm not a sysadmin, so I might say stupid things / rely on incorrect assumptions. Feel free to correct me.*

I work in a startup and some time ago we bought a server for internal use for a job. Now the job's over and we'd like to use it as 'computational workhorse'. The server can run virtual machines and we can control them via VMWare vSphere. I'd like to get a safe access to an instance of a linux vm (a debian one) via ssh.

My first approach would be to just keep the debian VM instance up and running, set up ssh and authentication with my RSA keys and port-forward 22 to any external IP on the internet (through the corporate router with firewall).

Is this unsafe?

Notice that there are no VPNs involved in the scenario described above.

Comment: Being safe is in the eyes of the beholder. If I were you I would at least use a different port. It is not un-safe per se as it doesn't expose you to any immediate and big dangers.

Comment: Thanks, by reading [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32308/should-i-change-the-default-ssh-port-on-linux-servers) it seems I can deal with most of the 'downsides'. Your point totally makes sense and I hadn't thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It could be safe**

It depends on your security requirements and level of risk you are willing to take.

Here are some considerations/ideas

- SSH is fairly secure, especially when forcing key authentication. Networks provide remote access via VPNs all the time. SSH is not much different.
- Password encrypt your SSH keys
- Enable automatic security updates
- You need to think about the rest of your network. The Debian server could provide an intruder with access to other network resources if it is ever compromised. Consider hardening it if you are worried about that.
- Maybe limit the VMs resources in such a way that it cannot interfere with the hypervisor or other VMs.
- If the VM has limited (DMZ or something) or no LAN/network access, it would be much safer. Consider multiple levels of firewalling, including a firewall on the VM itself.
- If the VM doesn't contain very sensitive information or important services, it would be safer.
- Maybe don't use the same keys or passwords for internal stuff or other servers other than that VM.
- Have something setup to watch the logs for unauthorised logins and/or other things of concern.
- Run ssh on a port other than 22 so people don't find it so quickly/easily/at all.
- Restrict incoming traffic via the firewall if possible (really safe, like if you have static IPs to connect from).
- Sometimes people/bots will hammer your server trying to get access. There are ways to rate limit or ban these connections. Your firewall may even be able to help with that.

**fail2ban ssh**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04